# Import Java project into Eclipse using Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I've written a java program that writes another java project.  However, I want to add a piece of specific code that will import the project into the workspace.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [here the same idea](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg72480.html) expressed by [Liran Orevi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72471/liran-orevi) but with some more details and a code example:

```
/**
* Imports the given path into the workspace as a project. Returns true if the
* operation succeeded, false if it failed to import due to an overlap.
*
* @param projectPath
* @return
* @throws CoreException if operation fails catastrophically
*/
private boolean importExisitingProject(IPath projectPath) throws CoreException {
    // Load the project description file
    final IProjectDescription description = workspace.loadProjectDescription(
    projectPath.append(IPath.SEPARATOR + IProjectDescription.DESCRIPTION_FILE_NAME));
    final IProject project = workspace.getRoot().getProject(description.getName());

    // Only import the project if it doesn't appear to already exist. If it looks like it
    // exists, tell the user about it.
    if (project.exists()) {
        System.err.println(SKTBuildPlugin.getFormattedMessage(
        "Build.commandLine.projectExists",  //$NON-NLS-1$
        project.getName()));
        return false;
    }
    IWorkspaceRunnable runnable = new IWorkspaceRunnable() {
        public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
            project.create(description, monitor);
            project.open(IResource.NONE, monitor);
        }
    };
    workspace.run(runnable,
    workspace.getRuleFactory().modifyRule(workspace.getRoot()),
    IResource.NONE, null);
    return true;
}
```

---

In [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg76588.html), you can also import projects which are zipped, with some code inspired from mostly scraped from `org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.datatransfer.WizardProjectsImportPage.java`.

Comment: ok, so the code is a little complicated (I'm cooking dinner too).  Can I simply call the existing ImportWizard and save myself writing this?

Comment: @Mechko: I am not sure, since I have not tested directly that code, but hopefully this can give you enough material for trying it out.

Comment: It seems to be correct, though I couldn't get it to work in the limited time that I looked at it because I don't know how to get the workspace instance variable.  I patched together a bash script that will do what I need for now (I need to run a java project that my java project generates.)  But I will need this eventually, so thanks a lot

Comment: You can get the workspace using

    ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace()

(Your plugin will need to depend on package org.eclipse.core.resources or plugin org.eclipse.core.resources, depending on how you like to specify dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to write an Eclipse Plugin.

Check those:

[Eclipse Plugins Exposed](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/02/09/eclipse.html)

[Eclipse Plugin Development - Tutorial (Eclipse 3.5)](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html)