# import existing project into eclipse using plugin or javacode

Tags: eclipse, import

If we want to import an existing project, we do the following

```
 File->import->general->Existing project into workspace->Select project….->Finish..
```

Can we do the same by using javacode or eclipse-plugin… Is there any such code available….

please help me...

Comment: I know what you mean.
[This maybe help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968369/import-java-project-into-eclipse-using-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IProjectDescription description = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().loadProjectDescription(  new Path("PROJECT_PATH/.project"));
IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(description.getName());
project.create(description, null);
project.open(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Very unclear what you want to achieve..

If what you are looking for is a way to easily to share a project setup between developers, then there is a way using [project sets](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-cvs-project-set.htm). The link uses CVS as example, but it exists for other version control systems.