# Import a Eclipse project using Java Code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pde

I have gone through the previous thread on the same [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968369/import-java-project-into-eclipse-using-java)

After reading that i tried to use the same code. I am very new to Eclipse plugin development. I tried to see the given example links but couldn't find the correct thread.

I have a similar requirement. I tried to develop a plugin following this [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html)

Should i compulsory develop a plugin or is there any way where i can run it from java main method.

Thanks,
Vamsi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have to write an Eclipse plug-in, as the suggested code re-uses existing features only available in an Eclipse plug-in environment.

For the referenced code to work, you have to maintain a plug-in with the dependencies org.eclipse.core.resources plug-in, and you also have to provide some functionality to execute this code (e.g. a platform command, as in another the mentioned vogella.de tutorial.

In theory, it might be possible to do it in plain Java code, but in that case it would make more sense to do it by directly editing the metadata files - and that is a way I do not recommend.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. i am confused on how to make the plugin Running and invoke the method which imports the project. I need help on this and how to configure the plugin. I am unsure on how a Non UI plugin will be invoked. I am a newbie in Plugin Development.

Comment: There are two ways: you can run a runtime eclipse (Run as/Eclipse application) - that will include your plug-in, where you can execute the command (e.g. from the UI). Or you can try to deploy your plug-in into the host (File/Export/Deployable plug-ins and fragments wizard), and there you can execute it. Until debugging, I clearly recommend the first solution. In all cases, it is your job to trigger your code (e.g. create an Eclipse Workbench command for it).